# not able to get ID of calling element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the id of element calling the function,
I have a div like this,

```
<div id="MainDiv"></div>
```

Below is the jQuery code,
when i keep a breakpoint and type `this`  I get the things info about the div, but I am not sure of how to get its id, i.e `this.id`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#MainDiv").Scrollit();
});
$.fn.Scrollit = function (e) {
    alert(this.id);
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the plugin `this` refers to the jQuery object, not a dom element so it does not have the `id` property.

You can iterate through the jQuery object using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and get the each element's properties - because the plugin can be initialized on a set containing more than one element

```
$.fn.Scrollit = function (e) {
    this.each(function () {
        alert(this.id)
    })
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6AG4L/)

Few pointers though

If you are developing a plugin don't depend on the id of the elements, use options or data attributes to pass informations

Also return the jQuery object back to enable chaining

```
$.fn.Scrollit = function (e) {
    return this.each(function () {
        alert(this.id)
    })
};
```

Comment: is there any other way of defining a function so that i can access this.id or $(this).id??
i.e to get the id of the element calling the function

Comment: @vignesh really why do you want to do it... you can of course use `$(this).attr('id')`